# Why is this particular website auto-formatting dates when parsed programatically?

Tags: date, io, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get a list of certain links from a website using Jsoup 1.10.1. The following is a snippet which I've isolated from the rest of my code in an attempt to diagnose the problem:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL link = new URL("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/gibbs/availability/1979-01-01");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(link, 600);
        Elements links = doc.select(".availableChannels > a");
        System.out.println(links.get(0));
    }
```

In theory this should print out the contents of the first link under the `.availableChannels`class on the provided URL, which should be `<a href="/gibbs/html/GMS-1/IR/1979-01-01-00" title="GMS-1 IR 0-UTC"> IR </a>`.

However, Jsoup instead auto-formats the yyyy-mm-dd date that appears within the a href, and as a result the code snippet prints out `<a href="/gibbs/html/GMS-1/IR/Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1979-0" title="GMS-1 IR 0-UTC"> IR </a>`, which is undesired.

How do I stop Jsoup from automatically formatting dates?

---

**UPDATE**

I decided to write a similar program in Python 2.7 to see what would happen if I read from that particular page (`https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/gibbs/availability/1979-01-01`). Turns out that the yyyy-mm-dd that appears in `<a href="/gibbs/html/GMS-1/IR/1979-01-01-00" title="GMS-1 IR 0-UTC"> IR </a>` is *still* getting formatted into `<a href="/gibbs/html/GMS-1/IR/Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1979-0" title="GMS-1 IR 0-UTC"> IR </a>` when I open and print the page's source using python.

```
import urllib

link = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/gibbs/availability/1979-01-01";
f = urllib.urlopen(link);
myfile = f.read();
print myfile;
```

I guess the question becomes: Why is this particular website automatically formatting dates when accessed through non-standard web browser means? I've changed the question accordingly to reflect this.

Comment: I think its not about the **Jsoup**, did you try the `curl`. when u `curl` this url, you will get the same thing, formatted as `<a href="/gibbs/html/GMS-1/IR/Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1979-0" title="GMS-1 IR 0-UTC"> IR </a>` . what do you think about this ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud that's very interesting. l'm not sure where the "EST" comes from, either, since my time zone isn't EST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you need to set the `Accept-Language` header on the HTTP request.

> The Accept-Language request HTTP header advertises which languages the
>   client is able to understand, and which locale variant is preferred.
>   Using content negotiation, the server then selects one of the
>   proposals, uses it and informs the client of its choice with the
>   Content-Language response header. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language)

So it seems like if you don't set the header, the server hosting the website returns a variant that doesn't use your preferred local time settings that you see in your browser.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL link = new URL("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/gibbs/availability/1979-01-01");

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link.toString())
            .header("Accept-Language", "en-GB").get();
    Elements links = doc.select(".availableChannels > a");
    System.out.println(links.get(0));
}
```

Output:
`<a href="/gibbs/html/GMS-1/IR/1979-01-01-00" title="GMS-1 IR 0-UTC"> IR </a>`